# Debugging HTML in WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, html, visual-studio-2010

I need to embed HTML in a Winforms project and call Javascript functions from it. I'm using a webBrowser control in a c# project and calling:

```
webBrowser.Navigate("website");
return webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("myMethod", new object[]{"test"});
```

How can I debug execution of code when the debugger is in "myMethod"?

There's this article on how to debug HTML from IE:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18921/Using-Visual-Studio-to-Debug-JavaScript-in-IE

I don't know how relevant it is though.

Comment: Have you tried the answer below?

Comment: @ParagM I get "Source code not found" when I try this solution.

Comment: Can you please specify in detail on which code line you are getting this error? If possible please provide a screenshot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add following "debugger" line in your website's "myMethod" function -\

```
function myMethod(arg1, arg2)
{
    // when myMethod executes you will get prompt that with which 
     // debugger you want to execute
    // then from prompt select "New Instance of Visual Studio 2xxx"
    debugger; 

    //
    ...
    ...
}
```

"debugger" statement will prompt for debugging the JavaScript.

When myMethod executes you will get prompt that with which 
debugger you want to execute then from prompt select "New Instance of Visual Studio 2xxx"

Hope this will help.

Comment: I had to uncheck `Disable script debugging (Other)` in Internet Options for this to work.

Comment: You can also attach debugger to the current instance of Visual Studio - just make sure you start your application without debugging.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the approach mentioned by Parag, you can also explicitly attach a debugger in Visual Studio and select **Attach to: Script code**.

[image]

Once that's done you get all open scripts to show up in Visual Studio as **Script Documents** and you can set breakpoints in any of those scripts. You can reuse the same instance for multiple debugging sessions. You also can open a JavaScript Console and DOM Explorer which gives you access to the same tools you'd get in full Internet Explorer.

[image]

More detail in a blog post here: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Jul/06/JavaScript-Debugging-in-a-Web-Browser-Control-with-Visual-Studio

> Note: Visual Studio 2019 makes script debugging a little harder to set up and unfortunately no longer supports the Console View/Evaluation window. You can still step and debug value, but no real time evaluation or seeing `console.log` output.